# Facebook comments moderation not working on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I have a my website which is [www.packages.almams.com](http://www.packages.almams.com) and i have implemented facebook comments with moderation. But comments are not showing at facebook moderation tool so that i can see all my comments.

```
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="title" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="www.packages.almams.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="www.packages.almams.com" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="desc" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="126739688050411" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100000106016242" />
    <meta property="fb:pages" content="158044824683299" />

 <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=126739688050411";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="www.packages.almams.com" data-width="600" data-numposts="5" data-mobile="true"></div>
```

kindly advice me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You must choose either `fb:app_id` or `fb:admins` but not both (source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/)